# Parallel run of the same function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

Say I have have the following 5 blocks of computation

```
load(var1.mat)
x01 = function1(var1);

load(var2.mat)
x02 = function1(var2);

...

load(var5.mat)
x05 = function1(var5);

save('file.mat')
```

where `var1 ... var5` are just some variables and `function1` is just some arbitrary function. I have a node with 24 cpu cores which I want to utilize. `function1` automatically accelerates to use 2.5 (3) cores, thus I want to calculate the 5 blocks in parallel and use 16 (3*5+1) cores. How do I do that? The outcome `x01 ... x05` is of varying length, so it is not trivial to just use a `parfor` and put it into a large matrix.

Comment: I think you can still use `parfor` and save the results into a cell array instead of matrix.

Comment: This sort of works. The only problem is that now a matlab worker from parfor only uses 1 core. Which half the efficiency.

Comment: Right. Then you have to use something different than `parfor` or somehow allocate 3 cores for each `parfor` worker. No idea if that's even possible :D